# Allocating multiple threads in python to a command line tool

Tags: python, linux, python-multithreading

First of all, I have very limited knowledge when it comes to this topic but I am curious if it is possible at all. I have a number of large data samples that must be processed with a command line tool in Linux. I can use about 14 threads, but the tool does not use all threads. I am wondering if it is possible to divide the 14 threads into two 'groups' and then run the same tool on a different data sample in a parallel way, each with 7 threads. I read about multiprocessing, but from what I understand I could only use 1 thread for the tool (sorry if I am wrong here, this is from what I understand).

So my question is:

1. It it possible to make multiple groups of threads
2. Let my command line tool run in parallel using those groups

For example:

```
def function_to_run_tool(data_sample):
    cmd = 'command to run command line tool one one of the samples'

function_to_run_tool(sample) # This function runs in parallel on 7 threads per sample
```

Basically it would be cool to have some sort of workers with more than 1 thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a single program on more threads unless that program separates itself into threads. It's just like you would want your processor to run a program you make into more threads without coding it to do so: it can't. The solution to this is to either split your data into let's say 14 parts and have one thread for each of the parts, or if the tool is made by you then you can change it so that it makes use of more threads for each data set.

To achieve that behavior you can use the threading module as such:

```
import threading

sample1 = your_first_sample
sample2 = your_second_sample

def function_to_run_tool(data_sample):
    cmd = 'command to run command line tool one one of the samples'

thread1 = threading.Thread(function_to_run_tool, [sample1, ])
thread2 = threading.Thread(function_to_run_tool, [sample2, ])
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

The samples have to be passed in arrays to the thread constructor because it takes the whole array as *args for the given function

Comment: The command line tools that I use are capable of dividing the threads over the tasks they perform. So for me the main problem is to create groups of threads that can be used to run the same software in parallel...

Comment: Which is that tool if you could tell me? We can't really help without having so much info. Maybe it takes as parameters the threads it has to run if it can run it on multiple threads, or it has a parameter which tells it to run on x threads.

Comment: The tool I'm trying to run is called Pindel [link](https://github.com/genome/pindel). It does indeed take a parameter in which I can tell it how many threads it can use

Comment: I found it too, it's the -T option in which you can tell it to run on a specific number of threads, so you can try that. @Dominique M

Comment: I do understand that. But my point is more in the direction of: what if I want to run this tool twice at the same time, but with different samples. Let's say I want to give them both 7 threads to run

Comment: For that you can use the threading module from python. I'll edit my answer to adress that

Comment: Thanks for your help, it makes sense and I'll give it a try! I'll report back if it is a success :-)

Comment: Please do, I am eager to help!

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this, the tool will only use 1 thread even though I have specified that I want to use more than on thread @Ghosty Frosty

Comment: Then you can try instead spawning processes rather than threads, and calling it there. How do you know it only uses one thread? Do you only get the result from one of the threads? Do you get both but after a delay?